# What can we say about two bases A and B for which the conversion matrix to a third base C is the transpose of the other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transpose

I am examining a space (in $52$ dimensions).  I found $3$ bases in it: $A$, $B$ and $C$.
The conversion matrix of $A$ to $C$ is upper triangular with only $0$ or $1$ entries and determinant 1.
The conversion matrix of $B$ to $C$ is the transpose of the first.
What does this tell me about $A$ and $B$ (if anything)?

tx.

Comment: Examine the general situation you described, but in 2 or 3 dimensions and see if you find something. Chances are, if you do find something, it's going to generalize to 52 dimensions nicely.

Comment: Ok, tx.  That seems like a good (an approachable) idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not much. If I understand you correctly, you have $C = A \cdot U$ and $C = B \cdot U^T$. Since $U$ is invertible, this means $A = B \cdot U^T \cdot U^{-1}$. However, there is nothing really special about $U^T U^{-1}$: For an upper triangular $U$, its transpose is lower triangular and its inverse is upper triangular (both have all ones on their main diagonal). However, the product of an upper and a lower-triangular matrix is full and pretty arbitrary. Also, while $U$ is binary, $U^{-1}$ isn't. It is an integer matrix (since the determinant is equal to one) but its values can be positive and negative and much larger than one.

The only thing you do know is that the first column of $A$, $B$, and $C$ agree entirely, since $U$ must have a single one in its top-left corner.